# Extending line using switch boxes as j-boxes?

Tags: electrical, wiring

TLDR: can a light switch box be used as a j-box to extend a lead for a different circuitry?

I am removing a long section of a wall (shown with blue outline) and I need to rehouse some of the wiring of a circuit.
Right now I have a single lead coming from breaker box, through floor joists, into a 2-gang box (B) with light switches. Switch #1 powers under-the-cabinet lights, and switch #2 powers a kitchen fan. The same box also acts as a j-box for kitchen can light circuitry (actual switches for those are located elsewhere), and a range hood.

I am removing the under-the-cabinet lights, as well as the hood circuit, so I only need to power and switch the fan, and power the can light circuit. I will have a single switch (C) on the remaining section of that wall, but the lead is not long enough to reach it. The path from the breaker box for new wiring is a very difficult one so I'd rather not fish a new wire. But the existing lead can easily reach the 4-gang box (A) in a nearby wall/post.

Is it okay to use box A as a j-box to splice another run of 14/2 wire through ceiling joists to box C?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of box A, and also get us dimensions of the inside of the box? It's likely OK, but we'll need to double check to make sure we aren't overflowing box A here...also, why 10/2, by the way?

Comment: Why in heck are you using 10/2? do you have old aluminum wiring?

Comment: @threephaseeel thebox is quite deep. I actually wired it into a outlet box below that as it is an oversized box (they all are), and only had one 12/2 Romex coming into it. 10/2 was a typo, it’s actually 14/2.

Comment: @Ecnerwal it was a typo, sorry. I corrected it to say 14/2.

Comment: @David -- are you sure that 12/2 was on a 15A circuit?

Comment: @threephaseeel sorry, didn’t mean to confuse you. So the circuit I am splicing is a 14/2 15A breaker circuit. I am just using an outlet box of another circuit that happens to be a 12/2 20A.  The outlet is lower, under that A box (not shown in the diagram), so it was was easier to fish it up to that box. My splice will just be “bunking” with the 12/2 box, no funny business between them, lol.

Comment: @David -- can you get us the size of the  outlet box in question please? Also, make sure that all the grounds in the box are connected

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I don't know the exact volume but it's a deep ceramic box and there is ton of room. Are you saying that I should tie the grounds of the two independent circuits (15A and 20A) because they are in the same box?

Comment: @David yes, you need to tie all the grounds together...also, ceramic boxes aren't a thing, are you sure it isn't hard plastic?

Comment: @threePhaseEeel Guess it's hard brown plastic.  This is what it looks like https://www.gordonelectricsupply.com/p/Carln-2000-1G-3-1-8D-Switch-Box/5869990?gclid=CjwKCAjw74b7BRA_EiwAF8yHFJOvgTdzWEdFfFkC7uZ0ufabciPap9pE_GzVtA7hX4ruCKxMcMh2FBoCi1cQAvD_BwE

Comment: @troubleshooter -- if you're actually splicing a new incoming and a new outgoing cable in the outlet box, then you need to connect the grounds together; if the cable run is continuous all the way through, then it's better to just bypass the box altogether

Comment: @troubleshooter No. I’m trying to extend 14/2 that is too short to reach a destination but it can reach a switch  box A, as well as an 18cu outlet box below A, lets call it a box D. Box D terminates a 12/2 cable. I’m just borrowing this space  to splice another piece of the 14/2 over the (too short) 14/2 run so that I can hop to next destination C. This avoids a fresh run of 14/2 from breaker to C. As I understand threephaseeel suggested That I need to connect the grounds of the 12/2 and 14/2 in that D box.

Comment: Thanks, I got lost following the plan. So, do you still have yet to run a 14-2 from the main panel to the outlet box? I remember you saying you can reach the outlet box easier; I was just thinking to make it a little longer and go straight up to 'A' with that new wire, since you have to put that link in anyway (outlet to 'A'). Then you only need to splice there, and verify that it won't be over-filled. [-maybe I am missing something - Is the 14-2 panel to 'D' already ran?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to repurpose a switch box just to house a splice.

Comment: ...if there is adequate volume in the box. Or you can replace the box with a bigger box if there is not adequate volume in the current box.